# Wesbstorm LiveTemplate trick

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

[LiveTemplates](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/live-templates-2.html) in Webstorm and all IDEA family products one of those nice features that bring pure awesomeness to your coding. So for the snippet like this:

```
stylus = require "stylus"
```

I can set abbreviation (for example `rqr`) and set the template text like this:

```
require "$END$"
```

tell Webstrom that this is applicable for coffeescript and voila, I have to type only that:

```
stylus = rqr[TAB]
```

But, I thought: "can I go even further with this?" Can I somehow tell Webstorm to read the word that I typed right before the abbreviation (in this case it's `stylus`), and Webstorm would automagically put it between quotes and finish on the next line? Wouldn't be that cool?
So you would type: `express = rqr[TAB]` and it would finish that for you, expanding it into:

```
express = require "express"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, wow, wow! I actually found a better way to do that...

if I keep the same abbreviation and change template text into:

```
 $module$ = require "$module$" 
 $END$
```

it does want I wanted, but in the way cooler way!

So you can use your own variables in a template as long as you don't call them `$END$` or `$SELECTION$`

Awesome!